# Purchase Order instead or Purchase - Do not remove stock if order is made by specific user role

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, inventory-management

So as standard whenever something is bought the shop inventory is managed and the number of items in stock drops by the purchased amount.

Do you know a way to prevent this from happening if order would be placed by specific role of the user? For example wholesale customer purchase order that would be sourced from somewhere else, so that would not affect stock for standard customers on the website.